# Cause program crash on purpose in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, button, crash

I'd need a way to cause the program to crash on purpose when i click a button. But nothing comes to my mind that would still allow me to compile the program. any code that causes a hard crash for whatever reason. in particular i need it to close and not be able to continue. My beta testers need to test the recovery after crash feature. Thanks!

these things never happen when they should..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To effectively kill the process use `Environment.FailFast()` in a button click handler, like this:

```
Protected Sub buttonCrash_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonCrash.Click
    Environment.FailFast()
End Sub
```

This will not generate any exceptions, etc., it is the same as going to Windows Task Manager and killing the process.

Here is the documentation for [Environment.FailFast Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

How about just throwing an unhandled exception?

```
Private Sub btnCrash_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCrash.Click
     Throw New System.Exception("The program has crashed catastrophically!")
End Sub
```

Comment: huh! had no idea that this was possible! thank you very much! (can accept answer only in 11 minutes)

Comment: The only problem with this approach is if there are any exception handlers further upstream, they will catch and potentially eat this exception; `Environment.FailFast()` will not be caught by anything and 100% kill the application. In other words, this solution may not work 100% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

How about the [Environment.FailFast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100.aspx) method?

```
Private Sub btn_click(...)
  Environment.FailFast("Failure!")
End Sub
```